Does Buddha teach there are no men or women?
I read the following on an internet site:

First of all, there are no men or women, no gender at all. Only
arising and vanishing causes and effects.

Where are the notions above found in the Tipitaka? Otherwise, where are the above notions refuted in the Tipitaka?

As far as I am aware Buddha never taught that there are no men or women. Logically speaking it will be absurd to say that there are no men or women. Men are defined by penis and women are defined by vagina. The sexual organ is like any other organ of the body like brain , heart , kidney etc. You don’t say heart doesn’t exist. You may say heart is empty of self. Similarly you can say penis or vagina is empty of self. You can also say Men and Women are empty of self. In short , you can say men and women are empty but you can can not absolutely declare that men and women do not exist.

A hundred years ago, were we a man or woman? A hundred years from now, will we be a man or woman? The Buddha's teachings is not about how to be a man or woman but about how to go beyond being a man and woman. By holding on to a gender, is this the first step towards achieving this? Perhaps, this is what the statement, "First of all..." is pointing at.

@Desmon Who is the “we” you are talking about ? Nobody is holding on to a gender. Perhaps you have not understood.

To be honest the way it is answered seems confusing. It is saying that the concept of men and women is empty but yet they cannot be declared as non-existent which may be confusing to a casual reader. It appears to straddle both for and against while the other answers are either clearly for or against. Frankly, I would suggest further elaboration with references to Buddhist texts to support the “emptiness” view and yet not nullifying the gender notion.

@Desmon You are not alone in your failure to understand emptiness. Buddha himself said that the idea of Anatta is so simple yet so difficult to grasp. To understand emptiness refer to SN 35.85. You will find for example nose is empty but it is there isn’t it. Post you doubt and I will answer it.

"First of all, there are no men or women, no gender at all." - some people think this is "woke". The woke movement replaces one form of gender identity for another like non-binary or gender-fluid or transsexual. The conservative anti-woke folks assert the traditional binary gender identity based on gender-assignment at birth. What is the Buddha's view? He says all gender identity views are mental fabrication, attaching the self to concepts and also form. Gender identity views are self-views. In SN 5.2, nun Soma smashed through these gender identity views around 2500 years ago.

@ruben2020 There is no true documentation on the woke movement. But from what I understand, woke refers to inequality of human beings. Some beings are expected to keep quiet. How it related to gender , I am unaware of it. Some google employees got fired due to the woke movement. I don’t think it was due to sexual reason. Christianity has a role to play here but I don’t know how.

These suttas support the notion that gender identity is a mental fabrication, a self-view.

Then Māra the Wicked, wanting to make the nun Somā feel fear, terror,
and goosebumps, wanting to make her fall away from immersion, went up
to her and addressed her in verse:

“That state’s very challenging;
it’s for the sages to attain.
It’s not possible for a woman,
with her two-fingered wisdom.”

Then the nun Somā thought, “Who’s speaking this verse, a human or a
non-human?”
Then she thought, “This is Māra the Wicked, wanting to make me feel
fear, terror, and goosebumps, wanting to make me fall away from
immersion!”
Then Somā, knowing that this was Māra the Wicked, replied to him in
verse:

“What difference does womanhood make.
when the mind is serene,
and knowledge is present.
as you rightly discern the Dhamma.
Surely someone who might think:
‘I am woman’, or ‘I am man’,
or ‘I am’ anything at all,
is fit for Māra to address.”

Then Māra the Wicked, thinking, “The nun Somā knows me!” miserable and
sad, vanished right there.
SN 5.2


And how does unyoking come about? A woman doesn’t focus on her own
femininity: her feminine moves, feminine appearance, feminine ways,
feminine desires, feminine voice, and feminine adornment. She isn’t
stimulated by this and takes no pleasure in it. So she doesn’t focus
on the masculinity of others: masculine moves, masculine appearance,
masculine ways, masculine desires, masculine voice, and masculine
adornment. She isn’t stimulated by this and takes no pleasure in it.
So she doesn’t desire to yoke herself to another. Nor does she desire
the pleasure and happiness that comes from such yoking. Sentient
beings who do not relish their femininity are not yoked to men. This
is how a woman transcends her femininity.
A man doesn’t focus on his own masculinity: masculine moves, masculine
appearance, masculine ways, masculine desires, masculine voice, and
masculine adornment. He isn’t stimulated by this and takes no pleasure
in it. So he doesn’t focus on the femininity of others: feminine
moves, feminine appearance, feminine ways, feminine desires, feminine
voice, and feminine adornment. He isn’t stimulated by this and takes
no pleasure in it. So he doesn’t desire to yoke himself to another.
Nor does he desire the pleasure and happiness that comes from such
yoking. Sentient beings who do not relish their masculinity are not
yoked to women. This is how a man transcends his masculinity. This is
how unyoking comes about. This is the exposition of the teaching on
yoking and unyoking.”
AN 7.51


Thank you for your effort however, to me, SN 5.2 is about the absence of "I am". AN 7.51 appears similar, that is, not focusing upon & not being yoked.

I think men and women are a default teaching as there is action and result. So beings are born into a sex due to their past actions and results. It is said only a man can be Bramha, Mara, Sakka?, a wheel turning monarch and a Buddha.
But women can determine to be these things in the future.
The idea that there is no male or female is talking about the goodness of the heart. That one who practices, who see the Dhamma, it doesn't matter if they are male or female, they enter in to the True Nature of things through their own meditation and accumulated good action.
Also when one develops one pointedness in a meditation object, at that time the perception of oneness is known.
But there is the elements, there is kamma and result, there is suffering... there are men and women, male and female.
Buddhism is very clear about these things and explicitly outlines them through the texts. But if one is a man or a women, they can still attain to the Dhamma, to higher path and fruit if they practice.
Here is one example showing the sufferings of a women, not experienced by a man. (copyright 2013 - Bhikkhu Bodhi, SN 37.3, Wisdom Pub listed here for study purposes.)

“Bhikkhus, there are five kinds of suffering peculiar to women, which women experience but not men. What five?
“Here, bhikkhus, even when young, a woman goes to live with her husband’s family and is separated from her relatives. This is the first kind of suffering peculiar to women….
“Again, a woman is subject to menstruation. This is the second kind of suffering peculiar to women….
“Again, a woman becomes pregnant. This is the third kind of suffering peculiar to women….
“Again, a woman gives birth. This is the fourth kind of suffering peculiar to women….
“Again, a woman is made to serve a man. This is the fifth kind of suffering peculiar to women….
“These, bhikkhus, are the five kinds of suffering peculiar to women, which women experience but not men.”


In context, that quote was in answer to the topic of, whether a woman must become a man first in order to attain Buddhahood.
On way to answer would be to distinguish "Buddha" from "Arahant".
More relevant to your question:

The Tipitaka may suggest that being a "man" is not it either -- with the Buddha as mahāpurisa (DN 30)
Or suttas (e.g. SN 4.11) say that it's wrong to describe the Buddha as "possessed of form" etc.
The Buddha himself says more than once that he teaches only suffering and cessation

Sometimes gender is viewed as important -- e.g. in social contexts -- other times not.
IMO in context the quote was referring to the latter, though perhaps not literally enough for you.
Although its literary style is reminiscent of wrong view ...

There is nothing given, nothing offered, nothing sacrificed. There is no fruit or result of good or bad actions. There is no this world, no next world, no mother, no father, no spontaneously reborn beings; no brahmans or contemplatives who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the next after having directly known & realized it for themselves

... IMO it also reads like a paraphrase of the Heart Sutra (said to be an enlightened/realized context):

all of the five Skandhas are equally empty,
...
all phenomena bear the mark of Emptiness


Doesn't "mahāpurisa" literally refer to a man, where the Buddha uses psychic power to display the status of his penis? (His private parts are covered in a foreskin.
kosohitavatthaguyho hoti )

Thank you for your effort however the Heart Sutra does not appear relevant to the Tipitaka. But, yes, its literary style is reminiscent of wrong view.

I'd ask about that -- but there already seems to be a topic, mine might be a duplicate: Heart Sūtra root in Pali Canon?

One might argue there is man and woman, being afflicted in different ways:

“And why do you call it ‘form’ [rūpa]? ‘It is afflicted [ruppati],’
thus it is called ‘form.’ Afflicted with what? With cold & heat &
hunger & thirst, with the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, &
reptiles. ‘It is afflicted,’ thus it is called ‘form.’ -SN22.79


I still cannot find a reference saying there are no men & no women.
The Elder Assaji uttered this stanza:

"Of all those things that from a cause arise, Tathagata the cause
thereof has told; And how they cease to be, that too he tells, This is
the doctrine of the Great Recluse."

SN 48.22 appears to say without male & female, there would be no life.

Mendicants, there are these three faculties.
What three? The faculties of femininity, masculinity and life. These are the three faculties.
SN 48.22

AN 9.15 appears to say male & female are themselves 'causes & effects'. Thus the doctrine of arising and vanishing causes & effects does not appear to negate the reality of male & female.

'A boil,' monks, is another word for this body composed of the four properties, born (sambhava; co-production) of mother & father, fed on rice & porridge, subject to inconstancy, rubbing & massaging, breaking-up & disintegrating.
AN 9.15

